# Improving accuracy/brevity of regex for inconsistent url filtering

Tags: python, regex

So, for some lulz, a friend and I were playing with the idea of filtering a list (100k+) of urls to retrieve only the parent domain (ex. "domain.com|org|etc"). The only caveat is that they are not all nice and matching in format.

So, to explain, some may be "http://www.domain.com/urlstuff", some have country codes like "www.domain.co.uk/urlstuff", while others can be a bit more odd, more akin to "hello.in.con.sistent.urls.com/urlstuff".

So, story aside, I have a regex that works:

```
import re

firsturl = 'www.foobar.com/fizz/buzz'
m = re.search('\w+(?=(\..{3}/|\..{2}\..{2}/))\.(.{3}|.{2}\..{2})', firsturl)

m.group(0)
```

which returns:

```
foobar.com
```

It looks up the first "/" at the end of the url, then returns the two "." separated fields before it.

So, my query, would anyone in the stack hive mind have any wisdom to shed on how this could be done with better/shorter regex, or regex that doesn't rely on a forward lookup of the "/" within the string?

Appreciation for all of the help in this!

Comment: Do you really need to use `regex`?

Comment: Like many problems, there are many solutions. In python, it is easy and pythonic to iterate through the strings, separate by a delimiter (".") and just piece together what we need. So, I know it can be done easily outside of regex, but in the context of regex I'm curious if it can be done better than what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think that regex is just the right tool for this. Regex is pattern matching, which is put to best use when you have a known pattern that might have several variations, as in this case.

In your explanation of and attempted solution to the problem, I think you are greatly oversimplifying it, though. TLDs come in many more flavors than "2-digit country codes" and "3-digit" others. See [ICANN's list of top-level domains](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/tlds-2012-02-25-en) for the hundreds currently available, with lengths from 2 digits and up. Also, you may have URLs without any slashes and some with multiple slashes and dots after the domain name.

So here's my solution ([see on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sHO0ec/1)):

**`^(?:https?://)?(?:[^/]+\.)*([^/]+\.[a-z]{2,})`**

What you want is captured in the first matching group.

Breakdown:

- `^(?:https?://)?` matches a possible protocol at the beginning
- `(?:[^/]+\.)*` matches possible multiple non-slash sequences, each followed by a dot
- `([^/]+\.[a-z]{2,})` matches (and captures) one final non-slash sequence followed by a dot and the TLD (2+ letters)

Comment: Thank you Brian, I appreciate this a lot! It operates on a lot fewer assumptions and is stronger against inconsistent strings. This is really helpful ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex instead:

```
import re
firsturl = 'www.foobar.com/fizz/buzz'
domain = re.match("(.+?)\/", firsturl).group()
```

Notice, though, that this will only work without `'http://'`.